# Uncaught ReferenceError: JSZip is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to save a selected set of rows from a table. The saveAs function is giving me this Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: JSZip is not defined
I have the FileSaver.js, I even updated it as in https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js

Can someone help me on what is wrong with this ? What could I do differently to have the rows exported to excel? I am using param query

```
              {                                                         
               type: 'button',
               label: "Export",
               icon: "ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s",

               listener: function () {

                   //filter the selected rows.
                   this.filter({
                       oper: 'replace',
                       data: [{ dataIndx: 'Selected', value: true, condition: 'equal' }]
                   })

                   Blob = this.exportData({

                       format: $("#export_format").val(),
                       zip: $("#export_zip").prop("checked"),
                       render: true
                   });

                   //reset the filter.
                   this.filter({
                       oper: 'replace',
                       data: []
                   })

                   if (typeof blob === "string") {
                       blob = new Blob([blob]);
                   }
                   saveAs(blob, "RollManager." + format);

               }
           }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to include JSZip script. It should be in your Paramquery files e.g. "/jsZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js" like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[path to paramquery]/jsZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To import jszip in js, use `require` like this.

```
require(['<path-to js>/jszip'], function (JSZip) {
   console.log(JSZip);
   });
```

Pass `JSZip` wherever it is used.